# Environment requirements developing GWT GXT application

Tags: spring, gwt, ide, gxt

I have to maintain a web application built using GWT 2, GXT 2.2, RPC calls, Hibernate, Spring and MySql.
In order to debug the application server/client side, compile and work easily what are the minimum requirements (Windows Xp system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recommendation from GWT Team -**
[image]

Source - https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/the-future-of-gwt-report-2012
You can upvote GWT Dev Requests For compile time improvements - https://vaadin.com/gwt/report-2012/wishlist

Some other tips - [How to improve GWT hosted mode / compilation times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242045/how-to-improve-gwt-hosted-mode-compilation-times)

Comment: Thank you SSR now i see that i'am not the only one who can take a break while GWT compile ;)

Comment: Welcome to the club!!! Coffee, Tea, Toffee, Table Tennis, Browsing on Smartphone browsing can keep you occupied. Jokes apart upvote on the Vaadin site for dev time compilation. Throw in Hardware. It pays off in long term :)

Comment: Not sure if I understand the graphic right, a small project of mine has 6MB (with 6 permutations). I don't think it gets to be less then 5MB. And it takes 23,292s to compile (1 year old Laptop). So what are those 100k? Anyhow this is how good it gets you should mark it as answered.

Comment: Try using GWT's <compileReport>true</compileReport> and     <compilerMetrics>true</compilerMetrics> to figure out the stats in your js files.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will work on nearly any hardware. It might simply take a bit longer to compile. I develope on a 3 year old laptop and it is fast enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i use Elcipse but the compile time take 6 minutes at minimum, and debugging server side in tomcat and client side by the google plugin it becomes really hard well not flexible i can say, and sometimes while debugging a RPC call in the server side the client throws to me an excpetion RPC Read Time out

Comment: Compiling 6min is okay if it is somewhat large. Debug mode should be nearly instant or < 1min. Seeing that you use XP your laptop might be just too old. If for some reason you really need to debug via tomcat, I can only recomend using lots of try catch and java.util.logging.Logger. The time out might be an endless loop? Write some time checking on your server code. Hope I could help

Comment: No the time out is not an endless loop, but when it comes i have to re-Debug another time to observe my code and do it quickly. My laptop is a dual core with 2GB or RAM, it's an ASUS, Windows XP SP3, 1.5 GHz each CPU

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand your problem. Is the time out only happening if deployed? Then you have a Server/Network problem, not a GWT problem. Is this happening in Debug mode? Is this happening randomly or only if certain actions are performed. This can only be determined by doing lots of logging and break points. As for your original Question. The better your PC is the quicker the compiling and debugging will work. If its not fast enough for you then you answered your own question.

Comment: well i'm not a native english speaker ;D , the problem of the read timeout happen just in debug mode, when the client do call to the server side, i had breakpoints at the opening code calculating the client request, i don't know if there is a way to configure the timeout for rpc calls

Comment: the rpc calls timeoutbut is not the main problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [Google Plugin For Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) and then create your GWT project using Google Plugin For Eclipse and [configure gxt for your project](http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-ext-gwt/).

Comment: First thank you for your reply, yes as i said to Martin, how could i be productive if it takes to me 6 minutes at least, the only thing i did is to reduce compiling permutations to 2 permutations by restricting the compilation for the browser IE8, there is just one entry point in that project and i have not the rights to split the entry point into many :(

Comment: If you have a multi core CPU you can use "-localWorkers 4" parameter for concurrent compile to reduce compile time.

Comment: i have a dual core, and i tested compiling with that arg but it's still > 6 minutes. but in reality i think that arg will not be useful for me, because if i open the task manager (the process javaw.exe take 50%) and right click that process i see that is executed using CPU0 and CPU1 (it's by default for all processes)

Answer (score 0):

Well I've used -localWorkers 6 as argument and -Xmx512m for the VM, I've cleaned the old .class files, but still stuck on 6 minutes (my project is 9.5MB), the only thing i think could improve compiling time is to use a strong CPU fast enough

Comment: Hello may be what i will say could be a tip, yesterday i have cleaned the whole project from unused imports automatically and guess what, the time of compilation have decreased from 6 minutes to 3mins 20s so I have gained 2mins 40s that's great, i wonder how many unused imports were in this project, iwish this can help someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

The single most performance improvement I've made with all my projects is to **move my toolkit VM onto a Solid State Drive**.

For best results, upgrade your laptop system disk to SSD but if downsizing is out of the question, box a 60G SSD into a external case, hook it up to an ESATA port, and blaze through your compiles. USB 3.0 is a suitable substitute for esata but uSB cannot sustain the same peak throughput.

Comment: Also - this solution provides for better security (via TrueCrypt),  portability (laptop->desktop->cloud), easy backup, and keeps my customer's information completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was resolved since December :D , by reformatting my old PC, the compilation time took 2 minutes, using compilation just for ie8 and no other configuration, but your replies will be useful for me in the future ;)